# Authentication with Knock works in testing but not production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I'm using the Knock gem to implement jwt authentication. In testing, when I send the user credentials to the right url the jwt is returned as expected, but in production the same code returns a 400 response when credentials are sent. I've checked the credentials of the user in the production db match the ones being sent.

These are the passing tests:

```
  test 'get authentication token' do
    post '/knock/auth_token', {auth: {phone: @user.phone, password: 'password'}}
    response = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode @response.body
    assert_match /.*\..*\..*/, response['jwt']
  end

  test 'no authentication on bad credentials' do
    post '/knock/auth_token', {auth: {phone: @user.phone, password: 'invalid'}}
    assert_response :missing
  end
```

This is the curl command that gets a 400 error:

```
curl -v --data "{\"auth\":{\"phone\":\"my_phone_number\",\"password\":\"my_password\"}}" https://production.server.com/knock/auth_token
```

What's going on here?

**EDIT**
Here is what I found in the production log (I think this is the relevant bits):

> 2016-06-16T07:28:23.906814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
> path="/knock/auth_token?auth={%22phone%22=%3E%22my_phone_number%22,%20%22password%22=%3E%22my_password%22}"
> host=production.server.com
> request_id=33e6189c-bccb-432a-af64-78ef890fbb4f fwd="110.175.125.233"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=1714
>
> 2016-06-16T07:28:56.429852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
> path="/knock/auth_token" host=production.server.com
> request_id=86f182b9-c1a9-40c0-abaa-30d488194cb8 fwd="110.175.125.233"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=400 bytes=224
>
> 2016-06-16T07:28:56.406561+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST
> "/knock/auth_token" for 110.175.125.233 at 2016-06-16 07:28:56 +0000
>
> 2016-06-16T07:28:56.415192+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
> Knock::AuthTokenController#create as */*
>
> 2016-06-16T07:28:56.415960+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 400 Bad Request
> in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 2016-06-16T07:28:56.418134+00:00
> app[web.1]:  2016-06-16T07:28:56.418141+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is
> empty: auth):

Comment: What says the production log?

Comment: @devanand thanks, just put that in. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl statement doesn't form the request correctly.

I managed to get the desired response from the server by using Postman to submit the request, putting the JSON in body of the request using the 'raw' tab and setting the body type to JSON.